# Cannot get non-null responses from two async REST API in my Cucumber Test simultaneously

Tags: java, asynchronous, cucumber, gherkin

I'm getting an error when end2end testing with cucumber; when I'd like to assert that the responses coming from two different async APIs aren't null and match the expected contents as described in my gherkin spec.

Given two async endpoints one called endpointA and the other one called endpointB.

```
Scenario:
    Given the following streams endpointA and endpointB
    When I get the A message from the endpointA stream
    When I get the B message from the endpointB stream
    Then the response from endpointA should be
      | att1 | att2   | att3 |
      | 11111| 000000 | test |
    And the response from endpointB should be
      | r1        | r2    | r3     | r4     |
      | A00586-00 | 11111 | <null> | OK     |
    Then the responses from both endpoints should match the expectations
```

The step definition for the above gherkin is described below:

```
public class ABStep extends CucumberBootstrap {

    private CompletableFuture<GenericMessage<ResponseA>> endpointAFuture;
    private CompletableFuture<GenericMessage<ResponseB>> endpointBFuture;
    ResponseB expectedResponseB;
    ResponseA expectedResponseA;
    @Autowired
    private RestService restService;
    private Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    @DataTableType
    public ResponseA responseAEntryTransformer(DataTable dataTable) {
        return dataTable.asMaps(String.class, Object.class).stream()
                .map(row ->
                        ResponseA.builder()
                                .r1(valueOf(row.get("r1")))
                                .r2(valueOf(row.get("r2")))
                                .r3(valueOf(row.get("r3")))
                                .r4(valueOf(row.get("r4")))
                                .build()
                ).findFirst().get();
    }

    @Given("^the following streams (.+) and (.+)$")
    public void printTheFollowingStreams(String streamIdCreation, String streamIdAck) {
        log.info("getting from streams {} and {}", streamIdCreation, streamIdAck);
    }

    @When("^I get the A message from the (.+) stream$")
    public void callAmpereToA(String streamId) {
        endpointBFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> restService.getMessage(streamId), executor);
    }

    @When("^I get the B message from the (.+) stream$")
    public void callAmpereToB(String streamId) {
        endpointAFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> restService.getMessage(streamId), executor);
    }

    @Then("^the response from endpointA should be$")
    public void isExpectedToHaveTheFollowingCreationFromAmpere(DataTable row) {
        expectedResponseB = respBEntryTransformer(row);
    }

    @And("^the response from endpointB should be$")
    public void isExpectedToHaveTheFollowingResponseFromAmpere(DataTable row) {
        expectedResponseA = responseAEntryTransformer(row);
    }

    @Then("^the responses from both endpoints should match the expectations$")
    public void isActualMatchingExpected() throws JsonProcessingException, ParseException, JSONException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        AtomicReference<String> respBId = new AtomicReference<>();
        AtomicReference<String> respAId = new AtomicReference<>();
        CompletableFuture<Map<String, Object>> combinedFuture = endpointBFuture.thenCombine(endpointAFuture, (respB, respA) -> {
            respBId.set(respB.getId());
            respAId.set(respA.getId());
            return Map.of(respBId.get(), respB
                    , respAId.get(), respA);
        });
        try {
            Map<String, Object> combinedResults = combinedFuture.get();
            GenericMessage<ResponseB> actualResponseB = (GenericMessage<ResponseB>) combinedResults.get(respBId.get());
            GenericMessage<ResponseA> actualResponseA = (GenericMessage<ResponseA>) combinedResults.get(respAId.get());
            String actualResponseBStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(actualResponseB.getData());
            String expectedResponseBStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(expectedResponseB);
            JSONObject actualResponseBJson = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(parser.parse(actualResponseBStr)));
            JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedResponseBStr, actualResponseBJson, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
            String actualResponseAStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(actualResponseA.getData());
            String expectedResponseAStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(expectedResponseA);
            JSONObject actualResponseAJson = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(parser.parse(actualResponseAStr)));
            JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedResponseAStr, actualResponseAJson, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "core.models.common.AB.GenericMessage.getId()"
> because "respB" is null   at
> AB.bdd.stepdefs.ABStep.isActualMatchingExpected(ABStep.java:111)

And sometimes respA is null
I'd like to have a non-null response for both respA and respB

Any help is appreciated